# Remove the nasty 3D Border from an ActiveX Control within a C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, activex, activexobject, mappoint

I am using the Microsoft MapPoint 2011 ActiveX Control in a Windows Forms Host within a WPF Application and try to remove the nasty 3D Border. I already tried to set the following Properties without success:

```
axMapPointControl1.BorderStyle = 0;
axMapPointControl1.Appearance = 0;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I double checked it for you and your code seems fine. Is there something at runtime that might be overriding your settings?

Comment: One forum I read indicated that it is not adjustable. That's just how it looks. Bummer! Could you cheat by putting the control inside some container and make the container a little smaller? Like mask it?